# Laravel 5.1 - Ajax Navigation not working with Javascript history API

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1, html5-history

I'm currently working on an app that needs to load my views by ajax from navigation menu.

My menu:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="logo menu-link" data-route="index" href="{{ url('/') }}"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}" alt="my-app-logo"></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="menu-link" href="" data-route="studio">Studio</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu-link" href="" data-route="customers">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu-link" href="" data-route="bio">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu-link" href="" data-route="contacts">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/{page}', 'PagesController@loadPage');
```

My controller:

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    // Index
    public function index(){
        return view('pages.index');
    }

    // load page
    public function loadPage($page){
        return view('ajax.'.$page)->render();
    }

}
```

A view sample (here i pass pure html without extending the blade template):

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="studio">
        <div class="custom-area">
            <div class="page-title-box">
                <h3 class="page-number">N. 67</h3>
                <h1 class="page-title">Area Test</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
// in my document.ready    

// get url page name and load my view at refresh page
var urlFull = window.location.href,
    pageName = urlFull.split('/').pop();

// currently only my index has blade functions, other pages content is pure html
if(pageName != ''){
    loadContentPage(pageName);
}

// get view from browser's navigation
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    loadContentPage(pageName);
}

// Laravel setup for ajax calls
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content-wrapper')
    }
});

var route;
$('.menu-link').on('click', function(){

    // active link
    $('.menu-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // load content
    route = $(this).data('route');

    // If i pass an empty string to simply call my index, in console i have an error(*)
    if(route == 'index'){ route = ''; }
    loadContentPage(route);

    // history
    history.pushState(route, null, route);

    return false;
});

// end document.ready

function loadContentPage(page){
    $('#content-wrapper').children().fadeOut(150, function(){
        $('#content-wrapper').load("{{ url('/') }}/" + page, function(data){
            $(this).html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

(*) The first problem is in the console i get this:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

If i refresh the page when i have for example `http://localhost:8888/app-test/public/studio` i get only the html, i'm wondering:

1. How to solve this
2. How to pass a second parameter in my route if i
   need a page detail like this:

   (Route::get('/{page}/{detail}',
       'PagesController@loadPage'));

**EDIT**: adding the variables within the function, history now can work:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    var urlFull = window.location.href,
        pageName = urlFull.split('/').pop();
    loadContentPage(pageName);
}
```

But i'm still stuck when i refresh the page on an url different from my index, `my-app/studio` returns only my view's content, pure html.
I think it could be a routes question but i still have no idea about it

Comment: have you considered using a SPA framework?

Comment: Sure, i was thinking to create this app with AngularJS but i was wondering if it was a good choice to have 2 frameworks (Laravel 5.1 and Angular) that have the same rules (MVC). Actually i work only with Laravel 5.1 and jQuery.

Comment: Why reinvent the ajax navigation wheel? See: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: Thanks, it seems cool, but if you see i've updated my question, and now my problem is focused on Laravel's route, because i need the entire page if i refresh the browser. Actually my route returns view's content, not the full page, i need to configure my routes in a clean way to get full views on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function loadContentPage(page){
var url = "{{ url('/') }}/";
    $('#content-wrapper').children().fadeOut(150, function(){
     if(page != 'index') { 
       url += page;
      } //end if you have other params update the url based on your routes
        $('#content-wrapper').load(url, function(data){
            $(this).html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: the function `loadContentPage` needs only one params: `route` (that's what i get from `data-route`), what you mean with the `page` params?

Comment: same result as mine my friend, i get only the view content (html) :(

Comment: you can hide the content of the index page and when the user clicks on the home link you just show it without doing ajax,you save a http request& bandwich